# Using a Node.js class in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am a new to Node.js and Firebase.
I have successfully tried to deploy some Cloud Functions to test them a bit.
I have a Node.js project in which I have a class defined as:

```
import * as Api from './api';

export default class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {[...]}

    someFunction(props) {
        return Api.someOtherFunction(props.arg1).then([..]).catch([..]);
    }
}
```

In the Api code I use the firebase admin SDK and I work with the real time database.Ex.:

```
ref.child(`users/${userId}`).set({
            id: userId,
            arg1: arg1,
            arg2: arg2
        });
```

Now, the problem is that I would like to use `MyClass` in a cloud function.
I have read a lot about ES6 in Cloud Functions, too (ex.: [here](https://codeburst.io/es6-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase-959b35e31cb0)), but I am not able to get rid of the error message

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I have tried to convert to require statements but I am not able to require my local module where `MyClass` is.
I don't care if it will be a Node.js local module or simply some classes in clear hierarchical structure.

What I would like to ask is if there is a specific documentation about this situation (I have searched a lot for it) and/or if I am following the right way to structure my project.
If the answer is "NO", please give me some tips on how to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions (node.js) currently does not support the ES6 `import` syntax, you have to use `require()`.

The examples in the article you linked are using Babel to convert ES6 to ES5. Even if you convert your `import` statements to `require()` you're going to encounter the fact that ES5 does not support the `class` syntax. If you want to do what the article it doing, follow the steps to get Babel converting your ES6 script to ES5 before sending it to Firebase Cloud.